# Using `numpy.vectorize` to create multidimensional array results in ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, scientific-computing

This problem only seems to arise when my `dummy` function returns an array and thus, a multidimensional array is being created.

I reduced the issue to the following example:

```
def dummy(x):
    y = np.array([np.sin(x), np.cos(x)])
    return y

x = np.array([0, np.pi/2, np.pi])
```

The code I want to optimize looks like this:

```
y = []
for x_i in x:
    y_i = dummy(x_i)
    y.append(y_i)
y = np.array(y)
```

So I thought, I could use `vectorize` to get rid of the slow loop:

```
y = np.vectorize(dummy)(x)
```

But this results in

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Where even is the sequence, which the error is talking about?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function returns an array when given a scalar:

```
In [233]: def dummy(x):
     ...:     y = np.array([np.sin(x), np.cos(x)])
     ...:     return y
     ...: 
     ...: 
In [234]: dummy(1)
Out[234]: array([0.84147098, 0.54030231])



In [235]: f = np.vectorize(dummy)
In [236]: f([0,1,2])
...
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

`vectorize` constructs a empty result array, and tries to put the result of each calculation in it.  But a cell of the target array cannot accept an array.

If we specify a `otypes` parameter, it does work:

```
In [237]: f = np.vectorize(dummy, otypes=[object])
In [238]: f([0,1,2])
Out[238]: 
array([array([0., 1.]), array([0.84147098, 0.54030231]),
       array([ 0.90929743, -0.41614684])], dtype=object)
```

That is, each `dummy` array is put in a element of a shape (3,) result array.

Since the component arrays all have the same shape, we can `stack` them:

```
In [239]: np.stack(_)
Out[239]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.84147098,  0.54030231],
       [ 0.90929743, -0.41614684]])
```

But as noted, `vectorize` does not promise a speedup.  I suspect we could also use the newer `signature` parameter, but that's even slower.

`vectorize` makes some sense if your function takes several scalar arguments, and you'd like to take advantage of numpy broadcasting when feeding sets of values.  But as replacement for a simple iteration over a 1d array, it isn't an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the error either, but with python 3.6.3 you can just write:

```
y = dummy(x)
```

so it is automatically vectorized.

Also in the official [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html#numpy.vectorize) there is written the following:

> The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

I hope this was at least a little help.